# How to explain the emergence of a distribution from different distributions?

Tags: probability-distributions

I am currently trying to understand how distributions emerge out of a simple calculation when combining data which have other distributional properties. What I mean with this is, as I am not a mathematician, is the following: Let's assume the following two equations

$\phi_{i,t}= \frac{S_{i,t}-C_{i,t}}{A_{i,t}}$ or $\phi_{i,t}=\frac{I_{i,t}}{A_{i,t}}$ where $S$ and $A$ are positive, $C$ is negative and $I$ can be positive and negative, too.

If I now plot the probability density function (PDF) over all $i$ in $t$ for the different variables and calculate $\phi$ a new "smoothed" distribution occurs. The plots look as follows:
[Plots](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ba9V7.png)

As I am not that familiar with the dynamics and properties lying behind that kind of process I would be very glad if someone could explain it to me or give me a hint where to look for the relevant literature.

Thank you in advance!
Best,
Alex

Comment: I don't understand this: you define $I=S-C$ and say that $S$ is positive while $C$ is negative, and yet $I$ can be positive and negative???

Comment: Hi @CarloBeenakker thank you very much for your for comment. Yes, because $C$ can also be larger than $S$ and thus $I$ can be negative in some case.

Comment: but surely, if $C$ is negative and $S$ is positive, as you write, then surely $I=S-C$ can only be positive???? (a positive number minus a negative number is always positive, isn't it?)

Answer (score 1):

In order to find the distribution of $\phi$, you need to know the *joint* distribution of $S,A,C$. Then you can use the standard transformation technique, as described e.g. in [Section 4.2](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=20&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=2ahUKEwj7pYzP48rhAhUKRKwKHRwgDY4QFjATegQIBBAC&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww2.econ.iastate.edu%2Fclasses%2Fecon500%2Fhallam%2Fdocuments%2FTransformations.pdf&usg=AOvVaw3uIFLAlD_1y6_t10iLuzUJ); see also bibliography there, including Casella, G. and R.L. Berger. Statistical Inference. Pacific Grove, CA: Duxbury, 2002; see, in particular, [page 185 there](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&ved=2ahUKEwifwZai78rhAhUGbKwKHeZ5BZIQFjAAegQIAhAC&url=https%3A%2F%2Ffsalamri.files.wordpress.com%2F2015%2F02%2Fcasella_berger_statistical_inference1.pdf&usg=AOvVaw01EzcwcV4uuax5RW7kze14). You can also read [Section 4.4.1](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=3&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=2ahUKEwin6KTv5srhAhUpgK0KHY_QAXoQFjACegQIBRAC&url=http%3A%2F%2Flibrary.aceondo.net%2Febooks%2FEconomics%2Feconometrics_mathematics-probability_and_statistical_inference.pdf&usg=AOvVaw2hJlUkgVF0uC7IOQr8S-m4), with several examples worked out there.

Comment: Thank you @Iosif! I will have a look at all the information you have provided!